# Lower bound for Ramsey numbers: $R( n + 2 , 3 )>3n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I need to prove the following inequality: $$R( n + 2 , 3 )>3n$$ where $n>1$ and $R(s,t)$ is a Ramsey number.

---

The most general way to prove such inequalities is to paint a graph with $3n$ nodes then show it could not have a sub graph with $n+2$ in red or $3$ in blue, I've also used induction but no answers yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you write what it would mean to prove that inequality?

Comment: The most general way to prove such inequalities is to paint a graph with $3n$ nodes then show it could not have a sub graph with $n+2$ in red or $3$ in blue, I've also used induction but no answers yet!

Comment: off topic= we dont understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I dont know how to make a picture.
Here I hope is an example Take $x_1,\cdots, x_n, y_1,\cdots, y_n, z_1,\cdots, z_n$

Make the $x$'s red. As are also the $y$'s and the $z$'s red.
Make $(y_i, z_i)$ blue and $(y_i, z_j)$ red.
Make $(y_i, x_i)$ blue and $(y_i, x_j)$ red.
Then
$(z_i, x_i)$ red and $(z_i, x_j)$ blue.
I submit this much before the question is closed.

Basically you have a set $X$ of size $n$ which is all red. Now for each $x\in X$ there is a blue pair $(y,z)$ with $z$ blue only to $x$ and $y$ red only to $x$.

Lets say there is a blue triangle. It has at most one $x$ one $y$ and one $z$.
They must be $y_i$ and $z_i$ for the same $i$ since all other pairs are red.
Now $x$ cannot be $x_i$ since $y_i$ is red with $x_i$.

Finally there is no $n+1$ red. It cannot have both $y_i$ and $z_i$ since these are blue. Thus from the $y$'s and the $z$'s there are at most $n$. And no pairs. This means there are at least two $x$'s Say $x_1$ and $x_2$ for convienience. Then I cannot have $z_1$ or $z_2$ since they are blue with $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively. Thus I have to have $y_1$ and $y_2$; but $y_2$ and $x_1$ are blue a contradiction.

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a little bit more in detail from the top and also what do you mean by Make $(yi,zi)$ blue and $(yi,zj)$ red, $(yi,zj)$ are the same edge.

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: @amirhosseinshafie Well I am assuming $i$ and $j$ are distinct.

Comment: are you using indirect proof?

Comment: @amirhosseinshafie I am giving an example and showing three is no homogeneous set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it's true.